# Does an NSApplication require an NSApplicationDelegate?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsapplication, nsapplication-delegate

I noticed that the [documentation for `NSWindowDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindowdelegate) reads (emphasis mine):

> A set of **optional** methods that a window’s delegate can implement to respond to events, such as window resizing, moving, exposing, and minimizing.

However the [documentation for `NSApplicationDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplicationdelegate) reads:

> A set of methods that manage your app’s life cycle and its interaction with common system services.

This does not have the word **optional**. I find that not including the delegate reduces the executable size of the application and that if I will only be using a **single window for the entire lifetime of the application** seem to be able to replace this:

```swift
public func applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed(_ _: NSApplication) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

With a the following method in the `NSWindowDelegate`:

```swift
public func windowWillClose(_ _: Notification) {
    NSApp.stop(nil)
}
```

The behavior appears the same however I could find no indication anywhere that not having an `NSApplicationDelegate` is officially supported by Apple. Are there any unforeseen consequences to this?

Comment: I'm curious to know the answer here, but I gotta say, this is quite a strange question! Just how much smaller would this make your binary? Are you _that_ space-constrained?

Comment: @Alexander Not *that* much smaller, but if I am making a truly tiny app, the size difference is a significant fraction of the app. On the order of a few KB.

Comment: Interesting! Is this one of those "smallest binary possible" challenges? I'd be curious to read more about your findings!

Comment: @Alexander Indeed. I am curious how small a very simple app can be. It seems much of the overhead of including extra delegate classes might be all the long method names of the methods, even ones that are not used/overridden by my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this doesn't appear to be *explicitly* documented, given the fact that

1. `NSApplication.delegate` is declared `nullable` (`@property (nullable, weak) id<NSApplicationDelegate> delegate`¹), so `NSApplication` is capable of having no delegate,
2. All `NSApplicationDelegate` methods are marked as `@optional`², so delegate objects are not required to respond to any protocol methods, and
3. It's entirely possible to set up and run an app by calling [`NSApplicationMain(argc, argv)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/1428499-nsapplicationmain?language=objc) from a bare Obj-C `main.m` with no other code/setup whatsoever

it's pretty safe to say that **you don't strictly need an app delegate to write an AppKit app** — you just won't be informed of app lifecycle events this way. The app delegate infrastructure, as it stands, exists to inform you of various events, but doesn't strictly depend on your responding to them.

---

[1][2] `NSApplication.h`, shipped with the macOS SDK, is not publicly available online, so I don't have a resource I can link to directly for this. If you're writing a macOS app, you can see the contents of this file by ⌘-Clicking a symbol found in this file, like `NSApplication`, `NSApplicationDelegate`, `NSApplicationMain`, etc.; or on disk at the macOS SDK path > `System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit/Versions/Current/Headers/NSApplication.h`

Comment: Plenty of people have uploaded `NSApplication.h` :) https://github.com/search?q=path%3A*%2FHeaders%2FNSApplication.h&type=code (and decompilations of most Apple frameworks, actually)

Comment: @Alexander Absolutely! I just didn't want to link to some random person's upload of the header as "official" justification — especially if the official header is already easily available via the SDK. But definitely, if you just search `NSApplication.h` online you'll find some copies

Answer (score 2):

The following source code creates a Cocoa window in Swift with menuBar without using an AppDelegate or xib.  To run in Xcode create a swift project and add a new file entitled 'main.swift' then add the code below to the the new 'main' file.  Delete the pre-supplied AppDelegate.

```
import Cocoa

// **** Menu **** //
 let menuBar = NSMenu()
 let menuBarItem = NSMenuItem()
 let app = NSApplication.shared
 menuBar.addItem(menuBarItem)
 app.mainMenu = menuBar
 let appMenu = NSMenu()
 let quitMenuItem = NSMenuItem( title: "Quit", action:#selector(NSApplication.terminate), keyEquivalent: "q")
 appMenu.addItem(quitMenuItem)
 menuBarItem.submenu = appMenu

// **** Window **** //
let _wndW : CGFloat = 400
let _wndH : CGFloat = 400

let window = NSWindow(contentRect:NSMakeRect(0,0,_wndW,_wndH),styleMask:[.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable], backing:.buffered, defer:false)
window.center()
window.title = "Swift Test Window"
window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(window)

let application = NSApplication.shared
application.run()
```